# Log or print to file SQL generated by Liquibase

Tags: maven, spring-boot, liquibase

This is a duplicate question, but I have not seen an answer to it, so I'd like to ask it again.

Is it possible to see / log (e.g.) create table sql with constraints and all? I mean just plain simple SQL.

I would very much appreciate an answer by someone who has her-/himself done that and been able to grab the sql statements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a built-in command in liquibase. If you run the `updateSQL` command, liquibase will generate the SQL that it would run if you ran the `update` command.

Comment: I will try that, I noticed that in the documentation of Liquibase there is an examle of that, that uses java -jar ...   I tried updateSql command with maven plugin, but it did not output SQL.

Comment: Here are the docs for updateSql in the maven plugin. https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/generated/updateSQL-mojo.html

It appears that the default is to write the output to a file: Default value is: ${project.build.directory}/liquibase/migrate.sql.

Comment: I kind of expected Liquibase to be able to figure out about drivers and changelog files just “by itself”, somehow from Spring Boot project. After adding mvn plugin config properties for driver and changelog file, Liquibase writes all SQL to file. (Thanks for help !)

Answer (score 3):

Custom SQL executed not showing up in 4.x versions of Liquibase with the INFO verbosity level.
Ref the issue discussion - [click here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1501)

As per latest update in liquibase, the sql logging level changed to FINE due to which in my application the sql logs stopped working. if someone facing the same issue then it can be resolved by doing these 2 steps :

1. override sql loglevel property using jvm argument  -> liquibase.sql.logLevel=INFO
2. change the logger level of executor -> liquibase.executor  level="INFO"

Hope someone finds this helpful :)